# swap service fabric in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I use Azure Service Fabric. My CI/CD in Azure devops. Everything is fine, but if i deploy my application to service fabric i see waiting for my application until it is updated and this is bad for users. When i use Azure "App Services" i can configure swap slots, add task swap slots in azure devops and this is best way for me. What i can configure in service fabric to avoid downtime? I read a lot of informations about how SF work with version, but i dont understand how this can help me. Please help me!

Comment: Service fabric uses rolling deployments, this is different from blue green deployments. I suggest you read about this types of deployments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need in release pipeline add “update publish prifile” and and select “ROLLBACK”. In your build pipeline I would recommend delete task about “copy” and “delete” *.pdb files